# 1d DFT of 3d function [video] in C using openCV

Tags: c, video, opencv, dft

I'm trying to compute 1d DFT along a GOP(group of pictures-basically a video) in C programming. I need to apply  the 1d DFT along the temporal direction to tranform the gop into a temporal drquency domain.
In this domain, the spatial information and temporal frequency information exist in the same frame.

So the 1D DFT of a video f(x, y, t) of size (M , N , T) in which, M x N is the size of each frame and T is the total number of frames in the GOP is computed by the following equation:

[formula equation](http://i46.tinypic.com/fkyzo2.jpg)

Does anyone know how can i handle this using openCV or something similar?

If you need any additional info, just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to compute the Fourier transform with respect to the time coordinate.

In order to do so, I think you need to reshape your 3D cube into a 2D matrix, where the vertical coordinate is the pixel index (in the range [0, MN-1]) and the horizontal coordinate the time (range [0, T-1]), i.e. each row contains the values of one pixel in the sequence.
You can then apply the DFT routine along each row with the `cv::dft()` function and the flag `CV_DFT_ROWS`.

**Matrix creation**

To create the matrix, you would proceed as follows (assuming a video frame has M rows and N columns):

1. Allocate a `cv::Mat` with **NM** rows and **T** columns, where T is the width of your time window (it can be a few frames or the while sequence length). Let's call this matrix **W** (for window).
2. For each frame I(.,.,t) in the window, copy each pixel I(x,y,t) (x ranging in [0,N-1], and y in ]0,M-1]) to the corresponding location in W, i.e. **W(y*M+x, t)**.

At the end of this process, W will contain in each row the temporally-varying values of one pixel. Then, call `cv::dft`on W with the flag `CV_DFT_ROWS`to limit the 2D Fourier transform to the horizontal direction, which is here the time.

Comment: I think i get your idea. But when you say "reshape your 3D cube into 2D matrix",how can i do that? I have as an input a .mpeg video which i capture using cvCaptureFromAVI. How can i proceed after that? 

Thank you for your response...